# makefile through vs-code (with makefile-tools) fails shell commands

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile, vscode-remote-ssh

I'm running VS-code on SSH mode (From WIN11 to UBUNTU server).

The C project uses a makefile.

The makefile 'collects' all the C files using 'find' command from shell:

```
SRCDIR := components/my_sources
SRCS := $(shell find $(SRCDIR) -name '*.c')
```

When I run 'make' through the terminal windows of VS-code, the make completes successully, while I am trying to build from VS-C, it fails:

```
find: ‘components/my_sources’: No such file or directory
```

I checked the 'find' command itself both in the terminal and in the makefile, and I see the difference. in the terminal I get a list of files, while from VS-Code 'build', I get empty list.

I also tried to use **full path** as input to the 'find' command. yet if fails

What should I define in VS code to make it work?

Comment: It looks like the working directory when you invoke things through VS Code is different than the one in your terminal.  You can find out what the directory is by adding `$(info current directory is $(CURDIR))` to your makefile and seeing what it prints.  As for how to change this, someone who know something about VSCode will hopefully help.

Comment: Indeed you were correct.

the current directory to be running was erroneous. (I thought that I can overcome it by using full path) .

Thanks

Comment: You could get at least the `find` to work correctly by setting `SRCDIR` to be a fully-qualified pathname.  But depending on what else your makefile does that might not be enough.

Answer (score 0):

As @MadScientist mentioned, the `make` command was running in an erroneous directory.

I had to update in `Makefile Tools` configuration, the field (as for v0.7.0):

```
***Makefile: Make Directory***

The folder path to be passed to make via the switch -C
```

Comment: what did you change the value of the setting to?

Comment: @starball - I changed it to the folder where the Makefile is